# MORRIS LINE GRAPH IN PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, graph, morris.js

putting multiple lines in graph.

in my project- xaxis- SP values- S
yaxis -CMH values

Each record in tables 
for each angle i have SP1 to SP10 and CMH1 to CMH10

For example:

angle 25 degree plot 10 point and form line- 10 point is(sp1,CMH1)(SP2,CMH2).... (SP10,CMH10)
26 degree again another 10 points as above line..

my dataset passing to line graph

> "result":[
>   {"BLADE_ANGLE_ID":1,"SP1":10,"SP2":5,"SP3":6,"SP4":6,"SP5":2,"SP6":2,"SP7":1,"SP8":2,"SP9":3,"SP10":2,"CMH1":12,"CMH2":null,"CMH3":null,"CMH4":null,"CMH5":null,"CMH6":null,"CMH7":null,"CMH8":null,"CMH9":null,"CMH10":null,"CHECKED":1},
>   {"BLADE_ANGLE_ID":2,"SP1":6,"SP2":7,"SP3":7,"SP4":23,"SP5":32,"SP6":4,"SP7":7,"SP8":9,"SP9":55,"SP10":45,"CMH1":10,"CMH2":null,"CMH3":null,"CMH4":null,"CMH5":null,"CMH6":null,"CMH7":null,"CMH8":null,"CMH9":null,"CMH10":null,"CHECKED":1
>   }]

Here you can see 2 blade angles and here u have to draw 2 lines with each 10 points(sp,CMH) for 2 different angles

Comment: Plz help me here I am working on this last 2 days

Comment: fortune plz dont edit my questiond

Comment: what do your have against edits ? They're done to ease/improve the reading of your question. For now you still didn't show any attempt to solve this by yourself, show us what you tried and where you're stuck, but don't expect someone to write all for you.